# How to describe persons who care about cost-effectiveness?

Tags: single-word-requests

How can I describe in a single word or two words a person who is sensitive in cost-effective stuff or products? Or persons who care the most for cost-effective stuff?

Comment: I'm looking for terms that can use in vehicles!

Comment: In vehicles?  Come again? // Frugal.

Answer (score 1):

You can describe such a person as being *economical*:

> 1 : marked by careful, efficient, and prudent use of resources : thrifty
>   // an *economical* shopper

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/economical))</sub>

'resources' here includes money which is available to spend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I have to name it, is it appropriate to say economical benefit seekers?

Comment: If it's to be used in the car rental business (like your other questions), I'd prefer "economical consumers" or something. "Benefit seeker" has some negative connotations you probably want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the word *skinflint*.

Answer (score 0):

I would say bean counter.

From [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bean%20counter):

> Beans are a cheap commodity, so to count them is a rather silly thing to do. A "bean counter" is one who nitpicks over small things in order to save costs. It is a derogatory term for accountants, bankers, and anyone who holds a financial interest in an endeavor.